Многосайтовость на "1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом"
Интересует такой вопрос: возможно ли реализовать многосайтовость на Битрикс имея одно ядро и две БД?
Одна БД1 для сайта1, другая БД2 для сайта2.
Понятно, что возможно реализовать многосайтовость на разных или одном домене, но из тех примеров, что я видел, предполагается, что используется одна БД.

Теоретически, да, но на практике придётся создавать свои компоненты, которые могут работать с разными БД. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=02379

@ВикторКарев благодарю, попробую с этим разобраться

А чем вам не нравится реализация на 1 БД? Через многосайтовость, это и облегчит работу контент менеджеру и администратору. Хотя теоретически возможно реализовать на ДВЕ БД, но вам придётся к этому ещё писать свои компоненты, для работы с 2-я БД + если вы развёрнуты на bitrixVm, там свои проблемы могут быть. В общем если вы реализуете, я бы хотел посмотреть. Заранее благодарен )

@Pirog мне все нравится, это не стандартный вопрос с практики, просто исследовательский интерес. Да, я  на bitrixVm. Но пока я изучаю в целом доступную документацию по этой теме...

@Pirog а можете рассказать о каких компонентах речь, пожалуйста. Вы имеете в виду компоненты для работы с БД, а не какие-то внутренние от bitrix?
